# Java custom annotations takes another annotation

Tags: java

how can I write a custom annotation that takes another annotation and the values?

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotation{
  Class<? extends TestAnnotationChild> annotation();
}
```

The second annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotationChild{

}
```

And I would like to do something like

```
@TestAnnotation(@TestAnnotationChild={values})
```

How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how it is done.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotation {
   TestAnnotationChild child();

   // Or for an array
   TestAnnotationChild[] children();
}
```

Usage

```
@TestAnnotation(
        @TestAnnotationChild(
               value = "42",
               anotherValue = 42
        )
)
```

However this part of your statement

> and the values

does make me think you want to do **something non-ordinary**.
Could you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

You should just use `TestAnnotationChild value();` instead of `Class<? extends TestAnnotationChild> annotation();`.

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotation{
  TestAnnotationChild value();
}
```

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotationChild {
    // String or whatever Object you want
    String[] value();
}
```

Now you can use the Annotations as you wanted:

```java
@TestAnnotation(@TestAnnotationChild({"TEST"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just have a property of type `TestAnnotationChild` in your `TestAnnotation`, just like it was a string, or whatever else